# Logging in with a different password than the database password, PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install PHPMyAdmin on my server to manage my MySQL databases. Right now I have only one I want to add, but I would like to be able to manage multiple databases from the same account on PHPMyAdmin.

How would I configure PMA so I could login with "andrew" and a password of "examplepassword" instead of the annoyingly long and unchangeable database user and password I am provided (ie. db3483478234, password of random characters)? I can't seem to find an area to specify a different password than the regular database username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin is just a MySQL client. Any credentials that you use to log into phpmyadmin must exist in the database.

Comment: Bummer... I ended up using the config option to auto-login to the database and protected the PHPMyAdmin directory. Seems to work ok for now and this is only a testing web server.

Answer (score 0):

Any mysql user with their password can login phpMyAdmin. Once you have installed phpMyAdmin, you can login with any existing/newly created mysql username & password.